# I ran pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y on command prompt. Will it affect my computer?

Tags: python, pip, environment

I ran it directly on command prompt, I forgot to activate my virtual environment. Now all my pip packages are gone, which i am not worried much about. But I am scared that it might have damaged my PC, there are no signs of it yet. Will anything happen to my PC?

Comment: What OS? Did you run that as root or as a regular user?

Comment: Windows 10, regular user.

Comment: On Windows, Python is not part of the operating system itself, so such command should not be a problem on Windows. Although looking at the command, it doesn't look like a valid command on Windows (`cmd`, or _Powershell_). My guess would be that you are using something like _WSL_ (Windows subsystem for Linux), which is quite a different story. But since you say you ran the command as a regular user, again it is most likely quite harmless.